# .getHours() для переменной

Tags: javascript

Планирую получить значение времени (часов) и если оно больше определённого значения то один вариант действий, если меньше то другой, ниже пример.

```
var time = new Date; // запускаем время :)
if(time.getHours()< 8:00 || time.getHours()>20:00){
   // ещё утро или уже ночь
 alert("Night");
}else{  // если не утро и не ночь
 alert("Day");    
}
```

Так не работает...
добавил новую переменную которая отвечает за часы

```
  var time = new Date; // запускаем время :)
  var timeHours = time.getHours(); // та самая новая переменная
if(timeHours < 8:00 || timeHours > 20:00){
   // ещё утро или уже ночь
 alert("Night");
}else{  // если не утро и не ночь
 alert("Day");    
}
```

Подозреваю, что не верно задаю условие времени, хотя компилятор не ругается. У кого так было? Как исправить что бы заработало?

Comment: просто посмотри какое значение ты получаешь при выполнении `time.getHours()`

Comment: @Grundy больше любопытно как условие может работать с не строкой вида `8:00` и `20:00` =)

Comment: @CoffeJava `timeHours < 8:00` Это неправильный формат. 8:00 измените на просто 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странно, что интерпретатор не выдает вам ошибку, на самом деле выражение `8:00` здесь некорректно, а для сравнения достаточно использовать `8` вместо `8:00` и `20` вместо `20:00`. Также нужно уточнить условие во втором случае:

```
var time = new Date;
var timeHours = time.getHours();

if (timeHours < 8 || timeHours >= 20) {
    // ещё утро или уже ночь
    alert("Night");
} else {  // если не утро и не ночь
    alert("Day");    
}
```

Comment: `Странно, что интерпретатор не выдает вам ошибку` - если бы еще кто-то смотрел в консоль...)

Comment: так автор вопроса ведь сказал что "компилятор" не ругается, а как там интерпретатор поживает не в курсе :)